# Azure AD Claims - Retrieve username

Tags: authentication, jwt, azure-active-directory, claims

I have a web application on App Service and I am using AAD B2C for authentication. My only Identity Provider is Local Account - User Sign up. I am trying to retrieve the user's username from the JWT token and add it as a claim but not sure where to do this. How can I add a claim to find the username that was used to sign up?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: Do note however that usernames are NOT unique and can change over time. Do not use them for authorization purposes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#using-claims-to-reliably-identify-a-user-subject-and-object-id

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain username by setting NameClaimType to preferred_username

```
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    // other configuration
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
    },          
});
```

then

```
User.Identity.Name
```

will be set to userName

Comment: I've tried this on a test tenant and application and it works, but then when switching to a different tenant (my client's) it doesn't work anymore. Does it depend on Azure AD configuration?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, username isn't available for selection as a claim to pass down in the token.

Also, Azure AD Team said that this is currently not on their roadmap. The workaround is to retrieve it by making a call through AD graph api.

[image]

Reference:

[include username in JWT claims](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13402104-aadb2c-include-username-in-jwt-claims)

[AD Graph API explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/)